# Track text cursor, to display menu above

Tags: java, cursor, markov-chains

I want to build predictive sentence advisor, like (Onion News) [Apple Introduces Revolutionary New ...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BnLbv6QYcA). Sentences can probably be generated by stylized pseudo-random text generating algorithm like Markov chain.

I imagine this as - while typing, menubox with predictive sentences are displayed above text cursor.

- How to 'text cursor track' and display menu over it
- What is the easiest way to implement Markov chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a tool tip on the text box be sufficient?  It can be recalculated on the fly.

Comment: Well i failed to think any better way, then to use taxtarea multiline tool tip with mnemonic keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5367619) will help you to track the cursor. I'm not sure how to convert cursor position to screen coordinates, but if you do it, [Popup](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Popup.html) will help you to display JList or JComboBox.

Don't know anything about Markov chain.

Comment: Following link seems to show how to get text character count. It does not seem to be useful. 

I was more like thinking some solution that does use 'StringMetrics' like class, to find string length and height (and do its thing).